# How can I disable the security warning in Foxit reader when I open links?

Tags: security, pdf-reader, foxit-reader

whenever I click a link inside a PDF document in Foxit reader I get this warning:

[image]

Is there a way to disable it?

Comment: You should add to your question that you have already unchecked *Enable safe reading mode* in Preferences/TrustManager.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Go TO -> **File -  Preference - Trust Manager - Internet Access from PDF...  - Changer Setting.** Then mark Allow PDF files to access all websites.